# Connect the if-else function to a database to get the different ids for storing the pallet types

Tags: anylogic

I would like to store my pallets into my pallet racks if the set conditions of my function are true. So now I have to **connect the function to the determine ids (typeIDs) in my database** that the function could loop through all entries in my dbase table and assign the pallet types to the pallet racks. After that the typeID should be resolved and when it comes to the store block the parameter typeID in my function should be connected to the dbase and the different ids get assigned to my deposit pallet racks PRD6,PRD7 and PRD8.
Could someone exactly say me how I could solve that?
I attached the dbase, the store block and the function.
Thank you for your help.

[image: dbase]

[image: function]

[image: store_block]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong approach, I think.

Your dbase table should create custom agents that you name "Pallet" (or similar). In there, you have a parameter `typeID`(integer).

You create those "Pallet" agents at the arrival time from the dbase and map the `id` column value to the agent's parameter `typeID` (see AnyLogic help and example models on parameter mapping).

Now, each Pallet knows its pallet-rack ID.

When the pallet needs to be stored into a pallet rack, that is when you use your function `getMyPalletRack` function (which must sit in your "Pallet" agent type).

cheers

Comment: Okay thanks i have done it. But the last problem ist that when I take typeID (int) into my arguments of the function that the error not resolved to a variable goes away it says method getmypalletrack(int) in the type Main is not applicable.

Comment: Please understand OOP. Your function is not on Main. But you are assuming it is in your call. Call it in the appropriate place (likely within the Pallet agent itself, where it should also sit)

Comment: I did a new post and could solve the problem. thank you for your help, I will improve your suggestion for my next posts.